# Positioning primefaces overlaypanel freely?

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

Now, I know about the `for, my and at` attributes for the primefaces overlaypanel, but I was wondering - can they be positioned freely? As in, without being associated with an element?

I have done this:

```
<p:overlayPanel 
    id="a123Panel" 
    widgetVar="a123Panel_w" 
    showEvent="none" 
    style="width:400px;height:50px; margin-left:auto; margin-top:50px; position:absolute;"> 

    ...
</p:overlayPanel>
```

But the margins or position attributes do not seem to make a difference. Resizing using those works fine however (400x50 px)

What I'm trying to do is use this as a pop-up window for extra input-fields in a form.

I have tried using the `<p:dialog>` element but it kept breaking my form in really strange ways (Like adding an input field to it for some reason caused my entire page to be duplicated and appended to itself whenever I clicked anything inside the form)

Thanks!

Comment: I think dialog should still be the way to go. Maybe the question you should be asking is the problem you're encountering using p:dialog.

Comment: Maybe it should be, but this is an easier way if there's a way to do what I asked above. The effort of making a working example out of what I have at the moment is way out of scale for the importance of this panel. I might revisit it later down the line but right now it's just a "Would be nice to have" kind of deal that I don't want to put too much effort into.

Comment: The source is open. You can always check there what happens when the overlay panel is shown: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/overlaypanel/overlaypanel.js#L172. Especially the 'align' function that is used in there is interesting. And regarding your last paragraph, that is a separate issue which is weird, not normal and most likely due to some wrong usage on your side.

Comment: @Kukeltje - I didn't think about that. Looking at the source actually provided some insight as to how things work, thanks.

Comment: Adding a postion:fixed solved it? Or did you not solve it yet

Comment: Adding a style tag as such didn't change the behavior, I'm solving it a different way currently.